# How does semantic scholar extract topics?

Tags: publications, bibliometrics, repository

I am looking for detailed information about how S2 extracts topics from documents. The only information I have found is this, from the [FAQ page](https://www.semanticscholar.org/faq):

*"We use machine language techniques to analyze publications and extract topic keywords that balance diversity, relevance and coverage relative to our corpus."*

This sounds similar to TF-IDF, but I would like to know the specifics of their extraction procedure.

Another question I have is how S2 relates the topics. When you click on a topic there is a sidebar showing related topics and also narrower and broader topics. Is there any information on how these relations were discovered, and is it possible to retrieve them?

Thank you in advance.

Kind regards,

Carlos

Comment: I imagine the methods used are a proprietary blend of standard statistical learning and machine learning algorithms. As a small taste, if you haven't seen it already, have a look at probabilistic latent semantic indexing and its partner latent Dirichlet allocation. Both attempt to discover topics. As far as how topics are related to each other, probably a mixture of manual and mining. Maybe not what you're asking for, but maybe of some help anyway.